# Tooling API Doesn't return Set/List/Map types

Tags: tooling-api

I'm trying to use to tooling API to retrieve information about methods within a class. While I do get the data, I noticed that the arguments for methods are incomplete. Any method that uses a collection as an argument does not list the type of collection. Here's an example from a constructor:

```
      "name":"ExampleClass",
        "parameters":[  
           {  
              "name":"ArgOne",
              "type":"String"
           },
           {  
              "name":"ArgTwo",
              "type":"Set"
           },
           {  
              "name":"ArgThree",
              "type":"Set"
           }
```

In this case, ArgTwo and ArgThree are Set<string>. This is not reflected in the data returned via the tooling API. Looking through the rest of the JSON document, I don't see this data anywhere. What's the deal??

Comment: I concur, I just pulled a SymbolTable for an ApexClass where a method took a Set of strings as a parameter. It only returned Set as the type. Is suspect this is more of a short coming than a bug, but you could try raising it as one.